# JOLT transformation from an array

Tags: jolt

I'm working in a transformation and it's working fine until I define the input as an array.
My current (working!) sample is:
INPUT

```
{
  "trainerName": "Nahuel",
  "trainingName": "1st Training",
  "trainee1firstName": "Martin",
  "trainee2firstName": "Para"
}
```

with this JOLT Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "trainerName": "trainerName",
      "trainingName": "training.[0].trainingName",
      "trainee1*": "training.[0].trainees.[0].&(0,1)",
      "trainee2*": "training.[0].trainees.[1].&(0,1)"
    }
  }
]
```

And the OUTPUT is:

```
{
  "trainerName" : "Nahuel",
  "training" : [ {
    "trainingName" : "1st Training",
    "trainees" : [ {
      "firstName" : "Martin"
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Para"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

This is perfect, BUT: the REAL expected input for me is this one:

```
[
  {
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "trainerName": "Nahuel",
    "trainingName": "1st Training",
    "trainee1firstName": "Martin",
    "trainee2firstName": "Para"
  },
  {
    "rowNumber": 2,
    "trainerName": "Nahuel",
    "trainingName": "2nd Training",
    "trainee1firstName": "Greg",
    "trainee2firstName": "Thomas"
  }
]
```

and I need an OUTPUT like this:

```
{
    "trainerName": "Nahuel",
    "training": [{
            "trainingName": "1st Training",
            "trainees": [{
                "firstName": "Martin"
            }, {
                "firstName": "Para"
            }]
        },
        {
            "trainingName": "2nd Training",
            "trainees": [{
                "firstName": "Greg"
            }, {
                "firstName": "Thomas"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I will receive the "trainerName" in every array object but I need to use only one.

Can you help me to find out the solution? I was navegating several solutions but couldn't find the right one for this sample.

THANKS a lot in advance! Bests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spec was almost correct. You need to have `[&1]` instead of `[0]`.

Also for trainerName taking `firstElement` using `modify-overwrite-beta` operation.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "trainerName": "trainerName",
        "trainingName": "training.[&1].trainingName",
        "trainee1*": "training.[&1].trainees.[0].&(0,1)",
        "trainee2*": "training.[&1].trainees.[1].&(0,1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "trainerName": "=firstElement(@(1,trainerName))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, very useful!